# Swift: make ellipsis continually retype in label? Tough label "animation"?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have seen no other questions on this concept - Im working in Swift and am doing a sort of loading page where I have a label that says something while the thing loads, similar to Sims. Like: "Checking our sources..."

As a cool animation, I want to have the ellipsis continually "reload" or "retype" so the label goes:

"Checking our sources." -> "Checking our sources.." -> "Checking our sources..."
and back again.

I have no idea how to do this and not sure if it qualifies as an animation. How can I constantly alter the text in a label to "animate" my ellipsis? I really would like to do this - is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have no idea how to do this and not sure if it qualifies as an animation. How can I constantly alter the text in a label to "animate" my ellipsis? I really would like to do this - is it possible?

All you are really describing is a label whose text is modified every so often. Or it doesn't have to be a label; it could just be a view that draws text, and you are redrawing the text every so often. You could easily implement a repeating timer (NSTimer) to do this, or you could use a custom animatable property and let the animation engine do the timing for you.

Took me about a minute to throw this together using an NSTimer, so how hard can it be?

[image]

If you like, you can use alternative "ellipsis" characters, or even images:

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks! Ive used timers before but are you saying I should every 3 seconds or whatever change the text (label.text = "") like that? Could you post an example?

Comment: So to be clear you are resetting the label.text each time?

Comment: Alright, I'm trying a different approach.. would you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38258197/swift-trouble-sticking-image-view-in-same-place-on-label-on-all-devices-even-w

Comment: Nothing, it just doesn't look as "pretty". I want to animate image views to "jump" in and can't do that with text

Comment: I had thought about having inline images - how would you do that? Do you know how to stick the 3 images/imageviews inline in a label? Swear to god the image views as subviews of the label is a nonstarter. Been 3 hours at this

Comment: Problem with adding the text is it moved the label to the left as I added ellipsis to it AND it just didn't look good. i want to scale the image as the ellipse comes in

Comment: Ok thank you but how would you do that? Im asking how you would add an image view inline a label - I figured out the adding ellipsis/NSTimer part fine. I don't know how to stick an image in a label - also can these inline images be animated/scaled?

Comment: Fine - to avoid being a leech, can you answer just the one question which you suggested in your answer - how to place an image (like an ellipse, an imagview not unicode) inline in a label? I would really appreciate it if you gave an example of just that. Please.

Comment: If you ask it as a question, I'll answer it. I'm not interested in discussing this in a comment.

Comment: Alright, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38273972/swift-how-to-add-and-animate-image-view-inline-in-label