# Swift: How to add and animate image view inline in label?

Tags: swift, label

In reference of [Swift: make ellipsis continually retype in label? Tough label "animation"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237046/swift-make-ellipsis-continually-retype-in-label-tough-label-animation/38237262?noredirect=1#comment63967128_38237262), I am trying to animate little image views to jump in and scale at the foot of some text in a label to create the effect referenced in the above question.

To do this I need to add these image views inline in a label and then animate them using UIView.animateWithDuration and some scaling, etc.

I do not know how to add these images inline in the label so they appear in the same place on the label regardless of device - how can I add image views inline a label in Swift?

Comment: @matt this is your area of expertise

Answer (score 0):

You don't "add image views"; you add *images* as part of the label's text. Use an NSAttributedString. You will need an NSMutableAttributedString so that you can modify it. Make an NSTextAttachment and set its `image` to your image (needs to be the desired size beforehand, easy to do). Call `NSAttributedString(attachment:)` to make a second attributed string consisting of the inline image, and insert that new attributed string at the desired index into your original attributed string. Set the label's `attributedText` to that.

Comment: Downloadable example project here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch10p507tabStops/TextTabTest/ViewController.swift